# convert euler angles to individual rotations about x, y and z-axis

Tags: rotations, angle

I'm doing some orbital mechanics and have calculated the Keplerian Elements (Euler angles) and now I want to plot it in 3D but I'm constrained to only doing rotations about the x, y or z-axis. I've seen how to convert the Euler angles to a rotation matrix but I haven't figured out a way to recover the rotation angles and the order that I need to do the individual rotations in. The software I have to use doesn't support matrices so if possible scalar or vector equations are preferred.

The Euler angles are intrinsic:

> intrinsic (rotations about the axes of the rotating coordinate system XYZ, solidary with the moving body, which changes its orientation after each elemental rotation).

Thank you very much in advance :-)

Comment: So you say that you already have the Euler angles? Those already correspond to individual rotations. Read the Wikipedia article, and remember that the Euler angle representation very much depends on the chosen rotation order (there are six different ones). For example, if you know that the rotation order is the extrinsic $xyz$-order and you have the Euler angles
$$
\alpha_1 = 15^{\circ} \qquad \alpha_2 = 30^{\circ} \qquad \alpha_3= 40^{\circ}
$$
it means that this orientation can be reached from the starting position (whichever that is) by first rotating $15^{\circ}$ around the $x$-axis,

Comment: ... then $30^{\circ}$ around the $y$ -axis and finally $40^{\circ}$ around the $z$-axis. So if someone says "Here are the Euler angles", there is some kind of assumption behind those angles, namely the rotation order.

Comment: I think I have the intrinsic angles: "intrinsic (rotations about the axes of the rotating coordinate system XYZ, solidary with the moving body, which changes its orientation after each elemental rotation)."

Comment: Okay, well that's one observation, good. This means that the angles are a bit trickier to calculate, than with extrinsic angles. But there is a key observation: An intrinsic rotation order is the same as an extrinsic rotation, when you reverse the rotation order (for example $xyz$ becomes $zyx$)! So you should only know the rotation order in order to understand its meaning. Are you able to experiment with the system, that is to input some angles and see how something changes?

Comment: I see, is this what's in the **Conventions** section of the Wikipedia article? Yes I can input the individual angles and see the result.

Comment: Then you must experiment and try to figure out the rotation order by trying out different angles and see how the orientation changes.

Comment: So if I know the intrinsic order is for example $zxz$ and my angles are $\alpha1$, $\alpha2$, $\alpha3$ then I should do: rotate $\alpha1$ around z-axis, rotate $\alpha2$ around x-axis and last $\alpha3$ around z-axis? (in other words no rotation around the y-axis)

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much Matti :-) Will try to experiment a bit with this now. Have a great day!